# Is it's possible use material-ui codemod v5 in project with flow types

Tags: material-ui, migration, flowtype

I want migrate from material-ui v4 to v5.
When i run codemode with:

```
npx @mui/codemod v5.0.0/preset-safe .
```

it's not working, in files where flowjs types declared as: (all files in my case)

```
type Props = {|
 +relay: RelayProp,
 +data: InsuranceTypes_data,
|};
```

I'm not see any instructions and issues about similar cases, how to simplify migration or use codemod in case with flowjs?

Answer (score 1):

Run the codemod script with --parser flag:

```
npx @mui/codemod v5.0.0/preset-safe ./ --parser flow
```